# undefined is not a function (evaluating '_app.default.database()')

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I got an error message when I tried to create a new employee (input data to firebase's database, do notice that it's not about email/password login as in from authentication tab). The problem appear only after I click the submit button (which should be inputting the user entered datas into database. Also, I should be connected to the firebase already since the register and login of email/password works correctly.

The error on android emulator's screen when on like this:
`undefined is not a function (evaluating '_app.default.database()')`

a line after that also state that there is an error at: `D:\Programs\reactnative\manager\src\actions\EmployeeActions.js:20:2`

From gradle info, these are what I use in practice:

```
"@babel/runtime": "^7.3.1",
"firebase": "^4.9.1",
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.58.4",
"react-native-router-flux": "^3.45.0",
"react-redux": "^6.0.0",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

Here's my code in EmployeeActions.js, which I believe involved in this error:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/auth';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import {
  EMPLOYEE_UPDATE,
  EMPLOYEE_CREATE
} from './types';

export const employeeUpdate = ({ prop, value }) => {
  return {
    type: EMPLOYEE_UPDATE,
    payload: { prop, value }
  };
};

export const employeeCreate = ({ name, phone, shift }) => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

return (dispatch) => {
  firebase
  .database()
  .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`)
    .push({ name, phone, shift })
    .then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: EMPLOYEE_CREATE });
      Actions.employeeList({ type: 'reset' });
    });
  };
};
```

I understand that there are quite a lot of 'undefined is not an object' error cases, but they often differs quite slightly from my case which made me confused. I'm pretty new at react-native myself, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

**require('@firebase/database');**

in the in EmployeeActions.js